# ReactJS: Problem with rendering component state

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to set up a form which upon hitting submit, should set the component state equal to the user entry so that I can store it and reference it elsewhere. This works as the console logs the correct string after submitting. However I run into trouble when trying to display this state on screen.

I've tried passing the state as a prop to a child component and have it rendered there, but I run into the same error.

```
import React from 'react';
var hasSetMainGoal = false;

class LearningGoals extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
                maingoal: ''
        };

        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.updateMainGoal = this.updateMainGoal.bind(this);
    }

    handleInput(e) {
        this.setState({ maingoal: e.target.value });
    }

    updateMainGoal = ({ target }) => {
        this.setState({ maingoal: target});
        console.log('My main goal is ' + this.state.maingoal);
        hasSetMainGoal = true;

    }

    render() {

        if (!hasSetMainGoal) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='setGoals'>
                    <div className='formField'>
                        <label className='formFieldLabel'>What is your main learning goal?</label>

                        <input type='text' id='mainGoal' className='formFieldInput' 
                        placeholder='' name='maingoal' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInput} />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.updateMainGoal}>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        );
        }
        else if (hasSetMainGoal) {

            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>My main goal is {this.state.maingoal}</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default LearningGoals;
```

I would want to have `{this.state.maingoal}` displayed on screen, but instead I get the following error:

> react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLButtonElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in h1 (at SetGoals.js:55)
>       in div (at SetGoals.js:54)

Comment: On form submit you are passing `target` which is object and is not renderable. Why do you set state by input and by button too? Btw. use `type='button'` in button or add `e.preventDefault()` to handle to prevent redirect on form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why you are getting this error

Your problem is in here, where you set the state to `target` but `target` is an object.

```
updateMainGoal = ({ target }) => {
    //                        target is an object
    this.setState({ maingoal: target});
    console.log('My main goal is ' + this.state.maingoal);
    hasSetMainGoal = true;
}
```

And when you try to render it, it fails because you can't render objects.

```
else if (hasSetMainGoal) {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My main goal is {this.state.maingoal}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And if you look at the error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLButtonElement])

`[object HTMLButtonElement]` is the `target` of `this.setState({ maingoal: target})`

## How to solve it

You shouldn't be doing `this.setState({ maingoal: target});` in `updateMainGoal`. Your state is already up to date when the user types in the input and `handleInput` sets the state for you.

What you should do is keep `hasSetMainGoal` in the state and set that when you click the button.

Here is the full component code

```
import React from 'react';

class LearningGoals extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
                maingoal: '',
                hasSetMainGoal: false
        };

        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.updateMainGoal = this.updateMainGoal.bind(this);
    }

    handleInput(e) {
        this.setState({ maingoal: e.target.value });
    }

    updateMainGoal = () => {
        this.setState({ hasSetMainGoal : true});
        console.log('My main goal is ' + this.state.maingoal);
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.state.hasSetMainGoal) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='setGoals'>
                    <div className='formField'>
                        <label className='formFieldLabel'>What is your main learning goal?</label>

                        <input type='text' id='mainGoal' className='formFieldInput' 
                        placeholder='' name='maingoal' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInput} />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.updateMainGoal}>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        );
        }
        else {

            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>My main goal is {this.state.maingoal}</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default LearningGoals;
```

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. I had pasted that updateMainGoal code from a tutorial, but I had made some sloppy mistakes in doing so. I've gotten it to work now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting hasSetMainGoal as variable, set it in state as false.

So rather than:

```
var hasSetMainGoal = false;
```

Do:

```
this.state = {
                maingoal: '',
                hasSetMainGoal: false
        };
```

and then set accordingly on button click, and check as:

```
if (!this.state.hasSetMainGoal) {
}
else if (this.state.hasSetMainGoal) {

       //your code
    );
 }
```